# heroku deployment build sucessfully but it is not verify my project

Tags: express, mongoose, heroku, heroku-cli

[image][image]

It is showing me this like when I start my development server in nodejs. But it is not
running further process. I tried it so many times but still getting same thing.

Comment: in your heroku project settings, do you have set buildpack to `heroku/nodejs`?

Comment: yes I have set heroku/nodejs and all config vars

Comment: what is in logs? `heroku logs --tail -a APP_NAME`. You might have issues with database and SSL certificate verification, if you use heroku database add-on

Comment: -----> Build
       Running build
       
       > ecommerce-website@1.0.0 build
       > node app.js
       
       Server listening in port 5000...
       Database connection successfully..